# Is it possible to combine two components?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives, angular2-components

I would like to implement [autocomplete](https://github.com/oferh/ng2-completer) within [ckeditor](https://github.com/chymz/ng2-ckeditor)

Both are angular components. Is it possible to **combine** them into one?

Comment: Why not make a master component with `autocomplete` and `ckeditor` as children in the template? you can then interact with them in your master component using 2 x `@ViewChild()` references.

Comment: How would you imagine that? I would have to somehow insert dropdown into ckeditor(I do not think that it is possible )

Comment: So what's stopping you from just editing the source code of ckeditor, and making it work how you want it to?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Autocomplete lists in CKEditor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28377886/autocomplete-lists-in-ckeditor)

Comment: @Delosdos I do not want to reinvent the wheel, so I thought someone must have faced very similiar problem